# is it possible to avoid array of arrays in JSON using sql query with join?

Tags: java, arrays, json, spring-boot

I'm not sure if it's even possible but I couldn't find any information about this (or didn't ask right question).

I write web app in Java/Spring and use my own queries (`@Query` annotation) in dao to get data from database. When I get data from one table everything is ok.

[image: one array is one row]

but when I join another table I get this:

[image: array of arrays].

My front-end guy, who gets data via JSON from me through url keep asking if I can change it so here is the question:
Is it possible to join table into one json array or it's just the way it is?

Sorry if it's a stupid question, probably I'm looking for something that doesn't even exist

Comment: If you map the data you're querying from the DB to Java classes (this is what ORM is for), you can then model your data on the server and Spring (via Jackson) will return the JSON form of it. Did you try that? https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany

Comment: not yet but I will try to change it this way
Thanks for respond!